# MapBox navigation sdk turn by turn using all points (co-ordinates) on map

Tags: android, dictionary, navigation, geojson, mapbox-android

I have a GeoJSON data which is giving me all the points (co-ordinates).
Using these points, I am able to draw polylines on map by using the following code.

```
mapboxMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .addAll(mapMatchedPoints)
                            .color(Color.GREEN)
                            .alpha(0.65f)
                            .width(4));
```

Then I want to do navigation through all the points on the map using this

```
 NavigationRoute.Builder navigationRoute = NavigationRoute.builder()
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken());

    navigationRoute.origin(origin);
    navigationRoute.destination(destination);
```

Here origin and destination points are needed. Listening to its callback method gives **routes** in following code

```
navigationRoute.build().getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
            if (response.body() == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                return;
            }

            // Print some info about the route
            route = response.body().getRoutes().get(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "Distance: " + route.getDistance());

            // Draw the route on the map
            drawRoute(route, origin, destination);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

drawroute is method which is used to draw navigation route

```
private void drawRoute(DirectionsRoute route, Position origin, Position destination) {
    // Convert LineString coordinates into LatLng[]
    LineString lineString = LineString.fromPolyline(route.getGeometry(), Constants.PRECISION_6);
    List<Position> coordinates = lineString.getCoordinates();
    LatLng[] points = new LatLng[coordinates.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
        points[i] = new LatLng(
                coordinates.get(i).getLatitude(),
                coordinates.get(i).getLongitude());
    }

    // Draw Points on MapView
    mapboxMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(points)
            .color(Color.parseColor("#3887be"))
            .width(5));
    mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(origin.getLatitude(), origin.getLongitude()), 18));

    mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(origin.getLatitude(), origin.getLongitude())).setTitle("Origin"));
    mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude())).setTitle("Destination"));
}
```

but it is not drawing through all the points.

It is only drawing from origin to destination avoiding intermediate points in between them.

As seen in this screenshot it's only showing from origin to destination.

[image]

I want it to show the route through the green marked polyline, and navigate through it.

I guess it is calculating the shortest path in between the points and drawing lines.

Comment: @All help would be appreciated

Comment: The direction you retrieved depend on the profile you set. But if you want to make sure it goes through some specific points you need to add these as waypoints when you make the navigation.Route call.

Comment: Thank you @David Olsson, will try and update you

Comment: there are some restrictions, iirc if you want traffic you can only set approx 3 waypoints (check the docs to make sure) and if it's 'mapbox/driving' iirc you can set up to 25. 
Create the request, then loop through and do navigationrequest.addWaypoint(waypoint)

Comment: but what if have more than 25, if i added more than 25 app is crashing, if i add 25 or less, then navigation is not getting completed
how i ll handle it, pls suggest?

Comment: Select waypoints that you know will make sure the routing engine selects that route (just an idea is the 9 corners your route has in the picture, it might just need 2 as well - test it). Are you sure you are handling the navigation result correctly with multiple legs?